# TFS 2013 - Can't build a project

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

When I try to **build** using TFS 2013, I get the following error:

If I try to access from external to http://lakebaserver.cloudapp.net:8080/tfs, it works, from the server it self, can't login.

Inner Exception Details:

```
Exception Message: VS30063: You are not authorized to access http://23.98.64.175:8080. (type VssUnauthorizedException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssHttpMessageHandler.<SendAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
```

The Build Controller is configured to use the FQDN:

[image]

This is the error:

[image]

Comment: What account is the build service running as? Is it a real service account? Did the password perhaps expire?

Comment: @DanielMann The build service is running on Administrator account. The problem is that the if I try to open http://23.98.64.175:8080/tfs from the server, the username password box is prompt but can't access. No problem if I access from externally.

Comment: Are you using the Administrator account in both cases? The build service account should be a domain account that is in the Build Service Accounts group in TFS.

Comment: Probably I was not really good to write the question: The problem here is that Build service is trying to access to http://23.98.64.175:8080 that is the the public IP of this VM !! I need to change the IP to the FQDN or to localhost! How can I change http://23.98.64.175:8080 to http://localhost:8080 or http://fqdn:8080 ???

Answer (score 2):

If I perform a nslookup of the dns name, the ip I get back is 23.98.64.175 (a public hosting IP in azure). Since your side comments talk about looping it back to the current localhost, I'm guessing this server is both tfs and a buildserver, named serverazure with the public dns name lakebaserver.cloudapp.net and internal name serverazure.lakeba.com.

If that's the case, because you are using multiple dns names for the localhost server, you are probably running into that the local loopback protection. Have you tried to disable that (using powershell):

```
New-ItemProperty HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa -Name "DisableLoopbackCheck" -value "1" -PropertyType dword
```